# Removing sound dampening windows for cleaning

Tags: windows, sound-proofing

I have sound dampening windows in my new home, they follow the style of the other windows. While most are on tracks and removable, the large picture window in the living room has a stationary middle window.

Unfortunately the two windows (*the normal house windows and the secondary sound dampening windows*) are quite dirty and need to be cleaned.  I cannot figure out how to remove the sound dampening window.

There are brackets at the top, but removing them did nothing. The window still seems very installed or stationary.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; let's see if you get a good answer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: With the brackets at the top removed can you lift straight up on the glass and swing the bottom out to you? Perhaps the screw on the side by the bottom is playing a role in securing it?

Comment: Looks like thermopane.. Factory sealed and not intended to be opened.  The plan is it is sealed and no dirt can can in, doesn't always work.

Answer (score 1):

May be there by sheer force of personality.  Get a set of suction cup handles used for moving glass.  Attach to glass and try moving it.

In light of comment by @Steve Wellens:

Sound deadening windows work by having thicker than normal glass.  Usually the two panes are different thicknesses.  The net result is a heavy window.

I suggest that you practice by using suction cup handles to lift and move a patio door unit.

Comment: Caution, it could be VERY heavy.